# Is there a more elegant way to write this If/or condition?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I have an if/or statement that checks messages To, Cc, and Bcc fields fo the presence of one of two emails.  The statement I have actually works fine.  But I wonder if there's a more compact/elegant way to write it:

```
var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(id);
var to = message.getTo();
var cc = message.getCc();
var bcc = message.getBcc();

if ((to.indexOf("EMAIL1")>-1)||(to.indexOf("EMAIL2")>-1)||(cc.indexOf("EMAIL1")>-1)||(cc.indexOf("EMAIL2")>-1)||(bcc.indexOf("EMAIL1")>-1)||(bcc.indexOf("EMAIL2")>-1)){  Logger.log("do some stuff")}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```
if (
  [to, cc, bcc].some(field =>
    ['EMAIL1', 'EMAIL2'].some(email => field.includes(email))
  )
) {
Logger.log("stuff")
}
```

Comment: This worked GREAT.  I'm not sure how this part works: `.some(email => field.includes(email)`  I don't have a variable named email.  But it seems to be working anyway.  Any idea why?

Comment: @DHol Read and practice the links provided in my answer. `.some` passes each element in the array as a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(id);
var to = message.getTo();
var cc = message.getCc();
var bcc = message.getBcc();

if (to.indexOf("EMAIL1")>-1||to.indexOf("EMAIL2")>-1||cc.indexOf("EMAIL1")>-1|| cc.indexOf("EMAIL2")>-1||bcc.indexOf("EMAIL1")>-1||bcc.indexOf("EMAIL2")>-1)
{  
Logger.log("do some stuff");
}
```

You can also try using arrays